# Menu bar not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, menubar

http://www.usplumbingshop.com/

The CSS works in Jsfiddle on Firefox, but not on my site.. Im not sure whats canceling out everything on firefox now. The site works fine with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: it works fine for me on firefox. what version are you using?

Comment: im using version 22.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but It is working in my firefox. I am using firefox 22.0. But your top phone number is showing beneath the search option.